# How to use normalize.css using npm install with webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, webpack

I am using webpack with ReactJS and trying to figure out how to using normalize.css after npm installing it (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Is the normalize.css applied right away after npm installing it? How would I make edits to it if I wanted to?

Answer (score 87):

You can use the npm-installed `normalize.css` in the following way with React:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import 'normalize.css'; // Note this

const root = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, World!</h1>, root);
```

The result will be:

[image: Text styled by normalize.css]

Notice that the text has been styled by `normalize.css`.

To get it working, you need something similar to the following setup:

---

1) Add the Javascript from above to `index.js`

2) Add `normalize.css` (and friends) to `package.json`:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "normalize.css": "^5.0.0",
        "react": "^16.3.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
        "webpack": "^4.8.3"
    }
}
```

3) Use the correct loaders in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { presets: ['env', 'react'] }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

4) Add an `index.html` file to see the results:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

4) Install everything

```
npm install
```

5) Start the Webpack devserver:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --open
```

---

**NOTE:** I am using version `5.0.0` of `normalize.css`. If you use version `6.0.0` or higher, the font will be different. All the opinionated rules were removed from `normalize.css` in that version.

---

**Update 17/5/2018:** Updated to use Webpack 4 and React 16.

Comment: I'm a React n00b, and found this via Google. As of today, the normalize docs show you the command line for 'npm install', but don't explicitly mention what the importable package name is (it differs from the install name), or how to utilize it after... therefore, I am very grateful for this answer. =)

Comment: I had to use `import 'normalize-css/normalize.css'`, just importing 'normalize.css would look for it in the current directory

Comment: @GreyVugrin `normalize-css` is not the same as `normalize.css`. `normalize-css` has not been updated since 2014: https://github.com/chrisdickinson/normalize-css

Answer (score 12):

Adding: If you are using WebPack 4 and you cannot import normalize.less, try normalize.css.

```
@import "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css";
```

And my rules:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                "css-loader",
                "less-loader"
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: This import is from inside another css file of course.. e.g. style.css

Comment: this may also be helpful for folks to resolve issues where -- when prev using style-loader -- styles were inserted into the head after imported styles, thus overriding custom styles with the defaults

Answer (score 5):

in index.css:

```
@import "~normalize.css/normalize.css";
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you `import` or `require` it will be included by Webpack unless you set it not to. For example:

> Note: I’m using Webpack 2.

```
module: {
    rules: [ // from 'loaders' to 'rules'
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.sass$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
              loader: ['style-loader','sass-loader']
            })
        }
    ]
}
```

The `exclude` property will take care of that.

Example:

```
// public/assets/style.scss
@import 'substyle1';
@import 'substyle1';

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```
// src/index.js -> entry file
import '../public/assets/style.scss';
// Webpack will know that you are importing your SCSS / SASS file
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify where I would do the `import` or `require`? And how would I be able to edit the normalize sheet?

Comment: Normally what I do is `import` or `require` it on my entry point usually `index.js`. Then webpack will take care of the rest. If you want to edit `normalize` sheet then you can do so as you would in a very simple project (directly editing the file itself)

Comment: Or in this case, since it's a node package, you can create a new `style.css` and import it in your entry file to make it available to all of your components.

Comment: Do you mind showing an example of how style.css should be created? Would that be the style sheet that holds all the styles? And I'm using SCSS by the way.

Comment: I updated my answer with a very simple example. It does not matter how you create your css / scss / sass file as long as you import it in your entry file, webpack will be the one to handle that. As long as a module is required or imported.

Answer (score -7):

First, install or download normalize.css from GitHub.I would recommend download it.Then, There are then 2 main ways to make use of it.

Approach 1: use normalize.css as a starting point for your own project’s base CSS, customising the values to match the design’s requirements.

Approach 2: include normalize.css untouched and build upon it, overriding the defaults later in your CSS if necessary.

i.e Just put these downloaded files into the project folder and add link to it by link tag

> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css"

**NOTE  href content should point to the folder where normalize is stored.**

Comment: Believe my question still stands. What if I npm installed it?