# Can not resolve path for css file inside node_modules while importing and building through webpack

Tags: webpack

I am trying to include normalize.css in my react component file through import "~normalize.css/normalize.css" but when trying to build its giving me this error message:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~normalize.css/normalize.css'

My package.json file is as follows and the webpack.config.js file is also given below.

```
{
  "name": "ccna",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "html-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "blueprint-css": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js file is as follows-

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

I am trying to import the style-sheet into a ReactJS component file.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import '~normalize.css/normalize.css';
import '../../css/main.scss';

import Header from "./Header";

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <>
                <Header/>
            </>
        )
    }

}
export default App;
```

Note: The main.scss resolves fine but the issue arises when i try to import any css or scss file from within /node_modules/ folder.

Comment: Your package.json does not list `normalize.css` as a dependency. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119878/how-to-use-normalize-css-using-npm-install-with-webpack/52130492 Gives a good explanation of how to use normalize.css in a Webpack based project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use normalize.css using npm install with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119878/how-to-use-normalize-css-using-npm-install-with-webpack)

Comment: @JoeHawkins its actually a dependency of blueprint-css and  exists inside node_modules folder.

Comment: Please share the stylesheet where you're attempting to import normalize.css

Comment: I am actually trying the import the stylesheet into a reactjs component file not inside a CSS stylesheet. https://pastebin.com/byAhik6N here is the component code in question. For reference the local main.scss resolves fine. Just the styles inside node modules are not resolved.